# Evaluated mesh data from edit mode

Tags: python

Is there a way to get evaluated mesh from within edit mode without using `to_mesh`?

`depsgraph.id_eval_get(obj).data` works only from object mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `to_mesh` is the only way of getting evaluated mesh from within edit mode.